# jquery and grabbing td title to tack on new td?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the titles from my td:

```
    function titleObject(table) {
        var titleArray=[];

        $('tr',table).each(function(i){
                var data={};
                $('td',this).each(function(j){
                        data[j]=$(this).attr('title');
                })
                titleArray.push(data);
        });
        return titleArray;
}
```

I am not sure this will work.  The next thing is I want to tack the title on to a td:

```
    function objectToTable(objectArray,table){
        var body=$('tbody',table);
        var color = colorStyleObject(table);
        var title = titleObject(table);

        body.children().remove();

        if(options.zebra){
                for(var i=0;i<objectArray.length;i++){
                        (i%2)?(tr=$('<tr class="'+options.zebraClass+'"></tr>')):(tr=$('<tr></tr>'));
                        for(var j in objectArray[i]){
                                tr.append($('<td class="ui-widget-content"></td>').html(objectArray[i][j]));
                        }
                        body.append(tr);
                }
        } else {
                for(var i=0;i<objectArray.length;i++){
                        tr=$('<tr></tr>');
                        for(var j in objectArray[i]){
                                tr.append($('<td class="ui-widget-content"></td>').attr(title[i][j]).css('background-color',color[i][j]).html(objectArray[i][j]));
                        }
                        //$('.ui-widget-content').css('background-color','green');
                        body.append(tr);
                }
        }
    }
```

This does not seem to be working.  The page just churns forever.  Am I getting the title correctly?  Am I not tacking it on to the new td line correctly?

Comment: Its a little difficult to help, since we don't know what the context is.  Could you post a link to the full page?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
var data={};
```

to

```
var data=[];
```

looks like you create data as an object and then try to use it as an array.

Comment: okay, I modified the .attr to be .attr('title',title[i][j].text()) too.  Now, the pager shows, titles shows, and the colors show, but the pager does not work.  That is another issue though.